# Raising compile-time errors

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to raise a *compile-time* error when a certain specialization of a function template is attempted ?

Say

```
template<typename T> T Factorial(T n) { ... }

short n;
cout << Factorial(n); // Error, short is too small
```

And is there a way to achieve the same effect for specific methods of a templated class ?

Say

```
template<typename T> class Arithmetic
{
  T n;
  T GCD(T m) { ... }
  T Factorial() { ... }
};

Arithmetic<short> A;
short m;

cout << A.GCD(m); // Ok
cout << A.Factorial(); // Error, short is too small
```

Comment: Take a look at [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Comment: Not the answer, but I suggest tagging with `c++` as well, as that tag has more exposure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: mh, doing this sometimes raises inflammatory comments about the version not being specific :-) Let's see...

Comment: @YvesDaoust, The guidance I would give is to use c++ if the question is about C++ and a specific revision tag like c++11 on top of that when answers should prefer that revision. (An answer for a later revision could still be useful to others.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://ideone.com/vqGLYx) could do the trick:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) > sizeof(short));
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<short> foo;
  return 0;
}
```

(mind that `static_assert` without diagnostic message requires C++17)

Comment: You can put `static_assert` outside of functions. No need for the constructor at all in this case, which can come with its own benefits.

Comment: @chris: not in this specific circumstance but you could need it if you have a template method in a template class, so yes it depends.

Comment: I have tried it and it seems to work the way I want. It is also possible to define generic method specializations that raise the error, and provide explicit overloads for those that you accept.